# How numpy dot works with broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays. When I used numpy dot function I got different results. I couldn't understand how dot function worked along with broadcasting to produce these outputs.
Can someone explain me the difference between these two.

```
A = np.array([[2,4,6]])
Y  = np.array([[1,0,1]])


np.dot(A,Y.T) = array([8])
np.dot (Y.T, A) = array([[2, 4, 6],
                        [0, 0, 0],
                        [2, 4, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dot` function is matrix multiplication, there's no broadcasting involved.
Using `np.dot(A,Y.T)` is the same as `A@Y.T` in python 3.5+.

Matrix multiplication is not commutative (the order of arguments matters).
In the first usage, A is a row vector, Y.T is a column vector.  This results in a single value.

In the second example, Y.T is a column vector, while A is a row vector.  This results in a matrix.