# No broadcasting for dot product

Tags: python, numpy

I tried this simple example in Python.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([20])
a + b # broadcasting takes place! 
np.dot(a,b) # no broadcasting here?!
```

I thought `np.dot` also uses broadcasting, but it seems it doesn't.

I wonder why i.e. what is the philosophy behind this behavior?

Which operations in NumPy use broadcasting and which not?

Is there another version of the `dot` function for dot product,
which actually uses broadcasting?

Comment: What does it say in [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)?

Comment: `np.dot(a[:,None],b)` works

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677675/1609514) "The dot function is matrix multiplication, there's no broadcasting involved".

Comment: What would you even expect broadcasting to mean here? This isn't an elementwise operation.

Comment: `@` broadcasts, but not in a way that would do whatever it was you expected to happen here.

Comment: `np.dot` is clear about how it handles all dimensions, and the `broadcasting` rules don't apply.  `np.matmul/@` is the same for 1 and 2d arrays, but its handling of 3d (and higher) dimensions does follow broadcasating.

Comment: @Bill I was looking for the philosophy behind this behavior. I knew what the docs would say.

Comment: @user2357112 I thought it was obvious what I expected here. The [20] array to become [20,20,20,20] and then to apply the dot product.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I suppose I can see how you might have thought that, but the actual behavior that would produce would be useless and nonsensical. If that was how it worked, then multiplying a 5x1 array by a 1x5 array would expand both arrays to 5x5 and produce a completely wrong result. Multiplying a 3x4 array by a 4x5 array would produce a broadcasting failure, because those shapes can't be broadcast against each other. Even for a vector-vector dot product situation, broadcasting like that would just hide bugs and add no useful functionality - `a.sum() * 20` would do the same thing faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't broadcast is because the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html?highlight=dot#numpy.dot) say so. However, that's not a very good, or satisfying, answer to the question. So perhaps I can shed some light on *why*.

The point of broadcasting is to take operators and apply them pointwise to different shapes of data without the programmer having to explicitly write `for` loops all the time.

```
print(a + b)
```

is way shorter and just as readable as

```
my_new_list = []
for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a, b):
    my_new_list.append(a_elem + b_elem)
print(my_new_list)
```

The reason it works for `+`, and `-`, and all of those operators is, and I'm going to borrow some terminology from [J](https://www.jsoftware.com/indexno.html) here, that they're *rank 0*. What that means is that, in the absence of any broadcasting rules, `+` is intended to operate on scalars, i.e. ordinary numbers. The original point of the `+` operator is to act on numbers, so Numpy comes along and extends that rank 0 behavior to higher ranks, allowing it to work on vectors (rank 1) and matrices (rank 2) and tensors (rank 3 and beyond). Again, I'm borrowing J terminology here, but the concept is the same in Numpy.

Now, the fundamental difference is that `dot` doesn't work that way. The dot product function, in Numpy at least, is *already* special-cased to do different things for different rank arguments. For rank 1 vectors, it performs an inner product, what we usually call a "dot product" in a beginner calculus course. For rank 2 vectors, it acts like matrix multiplication. For higher-rank vectors, it's an appropriate generalization of matrix multiplication that you can read about in the docs linked above. But the point is that `dot` *already* works for all ranks. It's not an atomic operation, so we can't meaningfully broadcast it.

*If* `dot` was specialized to only work on rank 1 vectors, and it *only* performed the beginner calculus rank 1 inner product, then we would call it a rank 1 operator, and it could be broadcast over higher-rank tensors. So, for instance, this hypothetical `dot` function, which is designed to work on two arguments, each of shape `(n,)`, could be applied to two arguments of shape `(n, m)` and `(n, m)`, where the operation would be applied pointwise to each row. But Numpy's `dot` has different behavior. They decided (and probably rightly so) that `dot` should handle its own "broadcasting"-like behavior because it can do something smarter than just apply the operation pointwise.

Comment: "The docs only handle the cases where the ranks are equal." - not true.

Comment: "They decided (and probably rightly so) that dot should handle its own "broadcasting"-like behavior because it can do something smarter than just apply the operation pointwise." - incidentally, it was later found that `dot`'s design was a bad idea. They picked a completely different design for the later `@` operator, and the `numpy.matmul` ufunc form of that operator. For dimensions >2, the `@` operator treats matrices as elements and broadcasts over all but the last 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 arrays and their shapes:

```
In [21]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
    ...: b = np.array([20])    
In [22]: a.shape, b.shape
Out[22]: ((4,), (1,))
```

By rules of broadcasting, for a binary operator like times or add, the (1,) broadcasts to (4,), and it does element-wise operation:

```
In [23]: a*b
Out[23]: array([20, 40, 60, 80])
```

`dot` raises this error:

```
In [24]: np.dot(a,b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.dot(a,b)

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (4,) and (1,) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
```

For 1d arrays `dot` expects an exact match in shapes; as in `np.dot(a,a)` to the 'dot product' of `a` - sum of its elements squared.  It does not expand the (1,) to (4,) as with `broadcasting`.  And that fits the usual expectations of a linear algebra inner product.  Similarly with 2d, a (n,m) works with a (m,k) to produce a (n,k).  The last of A must match the 2nd to the last of B.  Again basic matrix multiplication action.  It does a `sum-of-products` on the shared `m` dimension.

Expanding `a` to (4,1), allows it to pair with the (1,) to produce a (4,).  That's not `broadcasting`.  The `1` is the sum-of-products dimension.

```
In [25]: np.dot(a[:,None],b)
Out[25]: array([20, 40, 60, 80])
```

`dot` also works with a scalar `b` - again that's documented.

```
In [26]: np.dot(a,20)
Out[26]: array([20, 40, 60, 80])
```

`np.dot` docs mention the `np.matmul/@` alternative several times. `matmul` behaves the same for 1 and 2d, though its explanation is bit different.  It doesn't accept the scalar argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer in less-technical terms is that array broadcasting only makes sense for *element-wise* operations such as `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `**`.

Maybe this is what they mean by "arithmetic operations" in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting):

> The term broadcasting describes how NumPy treats arrays with different shapes during arithmetic operations

I agree it would be nice if they were more explicit about which operators allow broadcasting.

***The important characteristic of element-wise operations is that both arrays must be the same size***. This makes broadcasting behaviour easier to predict because it should always do the *obvious* thing to make the sizes match.

For operators that take a and b of different sizes, it may not be clear at all what broadcasting should do. Indeed, there may be more than one possible expected result that may seem obvious.

For example,

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
b = np.array([[10], [20], [30]])
print(a + b)

# [[11 12 13]
#  [21 22 23]
#  [31 32 33]]
```

This is quite clear.

But what should the result be if `np.dot` used broadcasting?:

```
np.dot(a, b)

# array([[140]])  # this is the actual result

# or
np.dot(a, np.repeat(b, 3, 1))

# array([[140, 140, 140]])  # with broadcasting of b

# or 
np.dot(np.repeat(a, 3, 0), b)

# array([[140],
#        [140],
#        [140]])  # with broadcasting of a

# or
np.dot(np.repeat(a, 3, 0), np.repeat(b, 3, 1))

# array([[140, 140, 140],
#        [140, 140, 140],
#        [140, 140, 140]])  # with broadcasting of both
```